# Unit tests with google authenticator

Tags: unit-testing, authentication

I'm currently using the 'Google Authenticator' app with a site that I'm working on and I was wondering if it's possible (whether Google provides it or not) to write unit tests that shows some possible outputs of the dual authentication program.

Rather than using a phone to generate the numeric code, I was wondering if there was also a class that allows me to generate it on my computer so that I could unit test the results.

Answer (score 2):

You can generate codes if you know the pre-shared secret string (one being encoded in QR code you scan with the Authenticator app). Here's a code in Python ([via @Tadeck](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8549884/1593459), [GitHub](https://github.com/tadeck/onetimepass)):

```py
import hmac, base64, struct, hashlib, time

def get_hotp_token(secret, intervals_no):
    key = base64.b32decode(secret, True)
    msg = struct.pack(">Q", intervals_no)
    h = hmac.new(key, msg, hashlib.sha1).digest()
    o = ord(h[19]) & 15
    h = (struct.unpack(">I", h[o:o+4])[0] & 0x7fffffff) % 1000000
    return h

def get_totp_token(secret):
    return get_hotp_token(secret, intervals_no=int(time.time())//30)

secret = 'MZXW633PN5XW6MZX'
for i in xrange(1, 10):
    print i, get_hotp_token(secret, intervals_no=i)
```