# What better way to create an access token in Python?

Tags: python, algorithm, token

I would like to create a token based on registration data from my client to be used to validate that our call center is attending a real client.

I'm thinking of generating a token based on your data exactly like tokens used in banks that change its value every minute. Is there any ready so I can create this token in Python library?

If not, is there any pattern (algorithm) for this? 
Create a token should not be so difficult, but what I would like is to do this within a standard, if any.

Thanks for help.

Comment: What libraries are you using, what code have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for a challenge token - normally called a one time pass, then these libraries are freely available.

There are two main ways to generate these tokens. HMAC-based (HMOTP) as specified in [RFC 4226](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4226) or time based (TOTP) specific in [RFC 6238](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6238).

The [Google Authenticator project](https://code.google.com/p/google-authenticator/) provides libraries for many languages to implement these algorithms and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8529265/google-authenticator-implementation-in-python) goes into detail on implementing it in Python.

However, for a call center application if your caller is authenticating themselves through the IVR, then you should use this to generate a token and send it to their registered mobile or email addresses for verification. It will be simpler to implement and as a bonus will also validate your customer information (if the customer's mobile/email is wrong, they can't utilize the call center).