# Taking the SHA1 HMAC of hex strings in Perl

Tags: perl, hex, hmacsha1

I have two strings (key and data) which are in hex string format, and I'd like to take the HMAC of them. The strings are:

```
$data = "0000000002ccbe80";
$key  = "48656c6c6f21deadbeef";
```

I want to produce the equivalent of the javascript jsSHA function where the strings are treated as hex strings. This demo http://caligatio.github.io/jsSHA/ lets you specify that the key and data are HEX strings.

However, when I use `hmac_sha1_hex($data, $key)` in Perl, the strings are treated as text. I get this output for the hmac_sha1_hex:

```
775083be8f8c94baea8d12a5038d191cab3759ac
```

How do I produce the same output as the jsSHA demo where both inputs are treated as hex and the output is also in hex? I want this output:

```
f2ea4899a8582c21610085988c54645fd7193393
```

Comment: Where are you getting `hmac_sha1_hex` from?

Comment: Apologies Borodin, I'm not quite sure I understand your question: I'm using Digest::SHA qw(hmac_sha1_hex) to compute the hmac of the key and data. But it seems to treat the inputs as text and I want them treated as hex, if that makes sense.

Comment: I didn't realise there was HMAC functionality written into `Digest::SHA`. I've added yet another solution to show how that works. But the key to your question is the use of `pack` to convert hex strings to binary.

Comment: FYI, your answer helped me answer my other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25534193/google-authenticator-implementation-in-perl/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know which module you are using to provide `hmac_sha1_hex`, but instead I recommend the `Digest` family of modules. If you use [`Digest::HMAC`](https://metacpan.org/module/Digest::HMAC) in combination with [`Digest::SHA1`](https://metacpan.org/module/Digest::SHA1) you can calculate a SHA1 HMAC, and the translation from a hex string to binary is done with [`pack`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html).

This code parcels the whole thing up into a subroutine for you.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Digest::HMAC;
use Digest::SHA1;

my $data = '0000000002ccbe80';
my $key  = '48656c6c6f21deadbeef';

print hmac_sha1_hex_string($key, $data), "\n";

sub  hmac_sha1_hex_string {
   my ($key, $data) = map pack('H*', $_), @_;
   my $hmac = Digest::HMAC->new($key, 'Digest::SHA1');
   $hmac->add($data);
   $hmac->hexdigest;
}
```

**output**

```
f2ea4899a8582c21610085988c54645fd7193393
```

---

**Update**

I overlooked that there is also a [`Digest::HMAC_SHA1`](https://metacpan.org/module/Digest::HMAC_SHA1) module that does all this for you and makes the code simpler still.

Like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Digest::HMAC_SHA1 qw/ hmac_sha1_hex /;

my $data = '0000000002ccbe80';
my $key  = '48656c6c6f21deadbeef';

print hmac_sha1_hex_string($key, $data), "\n";

sub  hmac_sha1_hex_string {
   my ($key, $data) = map pack('H*', $_), @_;
   hmac_sha1_hex($data, $key);
}
```

The output is identical to that of the previous code.

---

**Update**

Just to complete the set, this is how to do it using the procedural interface of `Digest::HMAC` instead of the object-oriented style.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Digest::HMAC qw/ hmac_hex /;
use Digest::SHA1 qw/ sha1 /;

my $data = '0000000002ccbe80';
my $key  = '48656c6c6f21deadbeef';

print hmac_sha1_hex_string($key, $data), "\n";

sub  hmac_sha1_hex_string {
   my ($key, $data) = map pack('H*', $_), @_;
   hmac_hex($data, $key, \&sha1);
}
```

---

**Update**

I've just read your answer to my comment. I didn't realise there was HMAC functionality written into [`Digest::SHA`](https://metacpan.org/module/Digest::SHA). Using that module and its `hmac_sha1_hex` call, all there is left is to perform the `pack` calls on the hex strings.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Digest::SHA qw/ hmac_sha1_hex /;

my $data = '0000000002ccbe80';
my $key  = '48656c6c6f21deadbeef';

print hmac_sha1_hex_string($key, $data), "\n";

sub  hmac_sha1_hex_string {
   my ($key, $data) = map pack('H*', $_), @_;
   hmac_sha1_hex($data, $key);
}
```

Comment: seems to me the part the OP is getting wrong is that _hex refers to the *output*, not the *input*

Comment: I did realize the _hex referred to the output, I was just confused how I could have the input treated as hex.