# How can I get a (time base) verification code like Google Authenticator (from the android app)

Tags: android, python, authentication, google-authenticator

I would to use an API on a website but this service is restricting some API methods with a 2FA. 
I really need to programmaticly call this restricted methods every 10 minutes interval.

I would to use a python script to get the time base verification code like Google Authenticator give us... 
but solutions given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8529265/google-authenticator-implementation-in-python) does not give me the same code with my mobile device and with python script.

[Here](https://github.com/google/google-authenticator) is the source code of the "Google Authenticator" project , but it is Java ... and I need (prefer) python !

My question is : where can I found a python script to generate exactly the same code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you looking for a 2FA that sends the user an SMS or Voice call which prompts them to enter a code?

Comment: No, I am looking for a python script that give me the same exact code like I see on my mobile with the google authenticator android app. Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally it is working with `python3` using https://github.com/pyotp/pyotp/tree/master/src/pyotp
example:

```
from pyotp.hotp import HOTP
import time

hotp=HOTP()

secret_KEY="12345678901234567890123456789012"

while 1:

   time.sleep(0.5)
   print(hotp.counter_from_time())
   hotp.generate_code_from_time(secret_key=secret_KEY, code_length=6, period=30)
```

which give:

```
(b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\n\x90\x90', 7.0)
('079310', 23)
(b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\n\x90\x90', 7.0)
('079310', 23)
(b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\n\x90\x90', 8.0)
('079310', 22)
(b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\n\x90\x90', 8.0)
('079310', 22)
(b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\n\x90\x90', 9.0)
('079310', 21)

[...]
```