# Interacting with Google Authenticator Using Cryptonite

Tags: haskell, google-authenticator, totp

I am trying to generate TOTPs such that I can make use of the Google Authenticator app. I am using the `cryptonite` library which provides TOTP functionality.

From my understanding, Google Authenticator requires the key in Base32. It also requires the `=` padding removed. Cryptonite provides an `unpad` function but I don't really understand how it works and as such can't figure out what the first argument should be, everything I've tried makes the function return `Nothing`.

For testing purposes I chose a key that would have no padding however, the codes generated by my program do not match those generated by Google Authenticator.

The Base32 key produced by the code is the following:

`GEZDGNBVGY3TQOJQGEZDGNBVGY3TQOJQ`

Entering this into Google Authenticator does not produce the same results as my code produces.

Here is my code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module TOTP
    ( genTOTP
    ) where

import qualified Basement.Imports        as Base (String)
import           Crypto.Data.Padding
import           Crypto.OTP              (defaultTOTPParams, totp)
import           Data.ByteArray
import           Data.ByteArray.Encoding
import           Data.Time.Clock.POSIX

genTOTP :: IO ()
genTOTP = do
    time <- getPOSIXTime
    let secret = "12345678901234567890" :: Base.String
        keyBytes = convertToBase Base32 secret :: Bytes
        key = keyBytes -- unpad (PKCS7 6) keyBytes -- I don't know what the first argument to unpad should be
        code = totp defaultTOTPParams key (round time)
    print code
```

In summary, I am unsure about how to unpad the `=` bytes from the key. Secondly, when testing with a key that had no padding, I still don't get the correct result.

EDIT: If it helps anyone, I did manage to find someone's implementation of Google Authenticator in Haskell without using `cryptonite` however, I still wasn't able to figure out why my code doesn't work.
[Google Authenticator in Haskell](https://gist.github.com/eungju/10379065)

Comment: @Carl Ok thanks for that. Even without `unpad` I don't get the correct codes, do you have any ideas why that might be happening?

Comment: I think you want `convertFromBase`, not `convertToBase`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question in the following question relating to an implementation in Python, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34001567/google-authenticator-code-does-not-match-server-generated-code?rq=1).

I was correct to convert the `secret` to base32 before typing it into Google Authenticator, but I didn't know that Google Authenticator converted it back from base32 to the regular secret before generating the code.

If I simply call `totp` on `secret` having entered `keyBytes` to Google Authenticator, I get the matching codes.

Comment: It may help to think of it like this: Cryptography is done on arbitrary bytes, but sending arbitrary bytes is often hard. So in transit, the bytes are encoded in some format that allows them to be represented as text - Base32 in this case. But the Base32 format is the transmission format. Use the raw bytes for cryptography.