# Is there a Google authenticator API

Tags: google-authenticator

I am trying to create a web app that is using a two-factor authenticator using the google authenticator, so my question is, is there an api for google authenticator?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Authenticator available as a public service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5087005/google-authenticator-available-as-a-public-service)

Answer (score 5):

The Google Authenticator app is simply an implementation of the Time-based One-time Passwords spec. See RFC 6238.

The algo takes the system time and a secret key to generate a token. The QR code communicates the secret key entropy and a helpful label for which service it's for, in a simple way to the end user.

The QR code is just a URL scheme which can be looked up. Do not use an online QR code generator, for hopefully obvious reasons.

It's best to use the above to read up on how you can implement this yourself, since no one on a QA site can recommend an API or SDK.

Trust no one.

Comment: Hi, noob here, its not obvious for me to not use online qr code generator, can you explain me why? And arent all qr codes online?

Comment: Hi Paul, the QR code is a convenient way for the seed key (a long random string) to get from your app into your customer's phone, else they'd have to type it all in somehow. An attacker with the seed can compute the time-based codes. Therefore, if you use a QR generator, you're sending your seed keys to that service. If you use a library, then check the code to make sure it doesn't post any data to a web server in some nefarious country, and doesn't do any debug/logging.

Comment: Ohh the library can steal it, that makes sense,  thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Worth mentioning that this `npm package` - [otp lib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/otplib), contains a decent implementation + it has a very nice [demo website](https://otplib.yeojz.dev/)

With lots of weakly downloads and very clear documentation, I say it's a great place to start. In a nutshell:

1. Generate a QR code for the user. This is required only for the first time (sign up)
2. Ask your user to enter one-time token (from the user's auth application)
3. Verify the token

So.. first step should be handled in server-side (to properly manage secret)

```
import qrcode from 'qrcode';
import { authenticator } from '@otplib/preset-default';
 
const user = 'A user name, possibly an email';
const service = 'A service name';
const secret = authenticator.generateSecret();

const otpauth = authenticator.keyuri(user, service, secret);
 
qrcode.toDataURL(otpauth, (err, imageUrl) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Error with QR');
    return;
  }
  // send `imageUrl` variable content to your client
});
```

On your app, you may generate the QR code using the same library

```
QRCode.toCanvas(canvas, imageUrl, function (error) {
  if (error) 
    console.error(error);
  else 
    console.log('success!');
});
```

The second phase is to actually build an input in your `sign in` page (to fetch token) and probably send it over to your backend again.

And the third part would be as simple as this:

```
const isValid = totp.check(token, secret);
```

Comment: Do not use this library without reading all lines of code, and all code in its dependencies and so on, and then taking actions to secure your dependencies. See https://snyk.io/blog/npm-security-preventing-supply-chain-attacks/

Answer (score 0):

This [one](https://rapidapi.com/chdan/api/otp-authenticator) is not free (freemium!)

1. Generate a "secret" code on behalf of your user:

```
import http.client

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("otp-authenticator.p.rapidapi.com")

headers = {
    'X-RapidAPI-Key': "KEY_GOES_HERE",
    'X-RapidAPI-Host': "otp-authenticator.p.rapidapi.com"
}

conn.request("POST", "/new_v2/", headers=headers)

res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()
```

Server will return you a secret code (e.g. IH225HMVWDS3XJVY). Keep it.

2. Generate QR codes for your users:

```
import http.client

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("otp-authenticator.p.rapidapi.com")

payload = "secret=IH225HMVWDS3XJVY&account=User1&issuer=HomeCorp"

headers = {
    'content-type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    'X-RapidAPI-Key': "KEY_GOES_HERE",
    'X-RapidAPI-Host': "otp-authenticator.p.rapidapi.com"
}

conn.request("POST", "/enroll/", payload, headers)

res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()
```

Server will return an url. Pull its PNG data and you get a QR code. Scan it with Google Authenticator app and you'll see TOTPs being generated every 30 seconds.

3. Now validate TOTPs:

```
import http.client

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("otp-authenticator.p.rapidapi.com")

payload = "secret=IH225HMVWDS3XJVY&code=425079"

headers = {
    'content-type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    'X-RapidAPI-Key': "KEY_GOES_HERE",
    'X-RapidAPI-Host': "otp-authenticator.p.rapidapi.com"
}

conn.request("POST", "/validate/", payload, headers)

res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()
```

Thats in Python (http.client lib), but the platform (RapidAPI) generates code snippets in most popular programming languages/libs like Java, PHP and others - quite handy

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).